# How to give default values and increase a specific one in mongoDB object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Im trying to increase one value in an object , while giving the others the default value if the document doesnt exist in the collection yet.

```
// the default should be 100 if the document is new : 

_id : someObjectId,
gameId : someObjectId,
votes : { 
a: 100,
b: 100,
c: 100
}

// my code : 

        function addVote(userVote) {
            userVote.gameId = new ObjectId(userVote.gameId)
            return mongoService.connect()
                .then(db => {
                    const collection = db.collection('totalVotes');
                    return collection.findOneAndUpdate(
                        { gameId: userVote.gameId },
                        { $set: { gameId: userVote.gameId }, $inc: {["votes." + userVote.vote] : 1 } },
                        { upsert:true , returnOriginal :false}
                    )
                })
        }
```

So my code right now creates the new document with the vote chosen + 1 .
any idea on how can i also give the default values on the same query ?

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: no , "mongodb": "^3.1.1"

Comment: Do you have any validation or schema in place for the `totalVotes` collection?

Comment: no didnt create validation or schema for this , can i give default value using the schema ?

Comment: In order to specify default values, you'd have to create a schema of some kind.  Schema validation wasn't introduced in MongoDB until v3.6 (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/)  This workaround should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953190/8332308